# Inner class coverage in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am currently working on writing Junits for a class which is present inside a class i.e. Inner class.

```
public class MainClassJob {
    public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<MyReport> {
        @Override
        public MyReport mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            MyReport r = new MyReport();
            r.setDate(rs.getDate("CS_DATE"));
            r.setFirstName(rs.getString("FNAME"));
            r.setFirstName(rs.getString("LNAME"));
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone guide me how I am cover the UserRowMapper portion as part of JUnit coverage report.

Comment: Create a test that forces the execution flow to go through the `mapRow` method. You tagged your question with "mockito" - anything in particular about it you wanted to ask?

Comment: That code won't compile, shouldn't the `mapRow` method be returning the `MyReport`?  Otherwise it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: That was just the sample code, My apologies! I have edited the code.
@GhostCat I want to write Junit code in order to cover that portion

Comment: That class is used as part of a method that executes a query to read MyReport instances from the database, right? So write a unit test that populates your test database with known test data, then calls that method, and checks that it returns the correct MyReport instances. And the mapper will thus be used, and covered.

Comment: it is already `public`, make it `static` and test it as all other classes.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer tells you how *technically* get to:

> Could someone guide me how I am cover the UserRowMapper portion as part of JUnit coverage report.

... simply by writing a test case that **runs** that code somehow.

But please note: you are asking the **wrong** question. You do not write JUnit test code in order to gain coverage. You write code so that you **test** your production code, so that you get failures when that code is wrong, so that you can later change your production code, knowing that there is step in place that will **verify** that the overall function is still correct.

In other words: you should ask yourself how to *meaningfully* test your code. Like: what is that code expected to do? What special cases exists? When should exceptions been thrown, ... and so on.

Then you write tests that cover all these aspects.

And then, finally, you might want to collect coverage information, so that you understand the *coverage* you gain from your test base.

Meaning: unit tests that don't do **any** asserts or checks, that only run to get you to 100% coverage, such tests are close to useless. The only thing they tell you: that you can run that code as is in a unit test without an exception popping up.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a factory method to create a `UserRowMapper`:

```
private MainClassJob job;

@BeforeEach
public void before() {
    job = new MainClassJob(...);
}

@Test
public void mapRow() {
    final UserRowMapper mapper = job.mapper();
    final MyReport report = mapper.mapRow(...);
    // verify the results...
}
```

If not then instantiate one using `job.new UserRowMapper()`, though the factory approach is cleaner and more intuitive.

That said, if the row mapper is not using any functionality or members from the parent class (which is the case in your example) why is it not `static`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the logic written in mapRow method, then you can easily create an instance and send mock result set and verify the argument

```
 MainClassJob mainClassJob = new MainClassJob();
  MainClassJob.UserRowMapper userRowMapper = mainClassJob.new UserRowMapper();
  userRowMapper.mapRow(mockResultSet,1)
```

But if your inner class does not need any member from the outer class, that means you should define it as a static class or , you should define it as a completely separate class.